# How can I strip a url with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have code such as this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/90Omh7_I8vI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to get just the url out of this so I end up with "http://www.youtube.com/embed/90Omh7_I8vI".

I'm sorry but I am not experienced with php enough, how could I do this?

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve? So popnoodles can give you the one and only qualified anwser in the whole universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How can I strip a url with preg replace?"

Using **exactly** what OP  asked, **preg_replace**, not preg_match or preg_match_all.

```
$string='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/90Omh7_I8vI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$src=preg_replace("/(.*src\=\")(.*?)(\".*)/", "$2", $string);
echo $src;
```

Comment: darma I **didn't downvote yours**. So you're a revenge downvoter and taking it out on the correct answer as the OP wanted it. How does that help OP?

Comment: Check my history and see that i'm a big helper of others here on SO. Always take my time to build nice answers, and hardly ask any question. But i'm so tired of arrogant "code police" like you, explaining others WHY their answers are so much better cause they are so clever.

Comment: Question: "How can I strip a url with **preg replace**?" Maybe if you answered correctly the "code police" wouldn't go around correcting you. When someone does point out an error I make, what do I do..? **I say thank you.** SO is for helping others.

Comment: There's also "preg-match" in the question tags + OP asked "so I end up with "http://www.youtube.com/embed/90Omh7_I8vI"." sooooo please give everyone a break.

Comment: Falsifying, when the history is there. Did I say "no you're lying"?  I don't believe so. Thank you for being so helpful on this matter. Correctness is paramount. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

With a regex like this :

```
if(preg_match_all('/src="([^"]*)"/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) >0){
    foreach($matches as $match){
        //$match[0] contains the whole 'src="url"' string       
        //$match[1] contains the url
    }           
}
```

Comment: "How can I strip a url with **preg replace**"?

Comment: OP wrote "end up with "http://www.youtube.com/embed/90Omh7_I8vI"." which is the url he seems to want to get in the end. i think he may have used "strip" the wrong way (not native english speaker?).

Comment: would you like to use gotomeeting to look at my screen or shall I make this -2? I did not downvote you. Grow up revenge-downvoter. You're downvoting a correct answer according to the question asked for no useful reason at all.

Comment: your name is so close to drama

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will select only the URL you want: `(?<=src=\")[^\"]*(?=\")`

Example:

```
preg_match("/(?<=src=\")[^\"]*(?=\")/", $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // <--- this will contain URL.
```